# JOOMLA - Add suffix to url

Tags: templates, url, joomla

I am using a joomla website with two template. the first one I assigned for a menu and the other one for a menu.
I want to add a suffix to the URL, so that I can know which template is being used.
Example:
for template 1, I have menu 1, if I am viewing item of menu 1, my URL will be:

```
mysite.com/abc/item-of-menu-1.html
```

And for template 2, I have menu 2, if I am viewing item of menu 3, my URL will be:

```
mysite.com/xyz/item-of-menu2.html
```

`abc` and `xyz` is suffixes that I can change by my self.
Please help me. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished by cheating the system a little bit. Make your menus like this:

Menu 1:

```
- abc   // Top level menu item, with alias abc
  - Menu item 1
  - Menu item 2
  ...
```

Menu 2

```
- xyz   // ...with alias xyz
  - Menu item 1
  - Menu item 2
  ...
```

The top level menu items can just be text separators. Make sure these are not displayed in the menu modules, there is a setting for this in the module. I believe the result will be more or less like you asked.

You might have to override mod_breadcrumbs if you are using breadcrumbs menu, and remove the top level menus, so it does not look weird.